# Emacs: execute function only after restarting, not after evaluating a buffer

Tags: emacs, startup

I like to start my work in Emacs with two open windows. For that, I have a function (split-window-horizontally) in my .emacs file.

It works with no problems, splitting window into two side-by-side windows after each evaluation of .emacs buffer. Of course, it also splits window every time I re-evaluate .emacs file to test some new setting. How can I tell emacs not to split the window after each evaluation of .emacs buffer, but rather only after restarting emacs?

I'm looking for something like:

```
(eval-only-after-restart
    (split-window-horizontally))
```

Is there any such function? Or another way how to do it?

Comment: Did you say _horizontally_? Horizontal splitting is so-so, go for vertical first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
(unless (boundp 'done-split-window-horizontally)
  (split-window-horizontally)
  (setq done-split-window-horizontally t))
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! Elegant solution.

Comment: What is `boundp` and `setq`?

Comment: They're elisp forms. They're all documented, so with your cursor on any of them type `<f1> f`
to find out what they do.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'split-window-horizontally)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-evaluating the whole buffer when you add new things, consider only evaluating the sexp that you added, by running `C-x C-e` at the end of said sexp.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I have a macro on `M-F12` that maximizes the emacs window (`M-x maximize`) and splits it vertically. Since I activate it manually, I decide when to do it and when not. What I'm trying to say is, that auto split at the beginning might be a good idea, but perhaps not the best one.